# Is it possible to create a custom order by function in postgres that alternate group of rows of specified dimensions?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, random, sql-order-by

I have this table "clients" with (id, name, offer_type) where offer_type can be 0, 1, 2 or 3.
Wrokin' with Rails, I'm trying to transport an algorithm from ruby to Postgres SQL ( due to performance reasons ) that first shuffles the clients and then orders them based on offer_type in this order:
4 clients with offer_type = 1;
3 clients with offer_type = 2;
2 clients with offer_type = 3;
1 clients with offer_type = 0;
4 clients with offer_type = 1;
3 clients with offer_type = 2;
2 clients with offer_type = 3;
1 clients with offer_type = 0;
4 clients with offer_type = 1;
3 clients with offer_type = 2;
...
And so on until i've ended every record.
Huge amount of rows to perform well in both memory and execution time.
 
I'm honestly having kinda a hard time tryin' to figure it out, for the "shuffle" part I used: 
`SELECT * FROM clients ORDER BY random();`
So about that I'm covered... For the actual ordering by offer_type I'm off sea, I've tried something found on this page https://www.gab.lc/articles/order_by_custom_list/ but it didn't actually help,'cause I ended having them sorted by blocks of clients with the same offer_type.
I was hoping someone could direct me to a page where it's explained something similar or if someone has some suggestion.

Comment: What should happen when one offer_type runs out before the others?

Comment: If for example the quantity of clients with offer_type = 1 end before the others, the others should keep the same pattern, so 4 clients type 1, 3 type 2, 2 type 3, 1 type 0, now type 2 clients finish, the rest should follow as 4 type 1, 2 type 3, 1 type 0 and so on until every type of client is over

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can do this with `row_number()` and integer division:

```
select c.*
from clients c
inner join (values(1, 4), (2, 3), (3, 2), (0, 1)) m(offer_type, seq)
    on m.offer_type = c.offer_type
order by
    (row_number() over(partition by c.offer_type order by random()) - 1) / m.seq,
    m.seq desc
```

Comment: Woah thank you! Worked like a charm. I didn't even know about row_number(), seems I should deepen my knowledge a bit, thanks again!